# Scala AbstractTypeU?

Tags: scala, types, compiler-construction

What is Scala's AbstractTypeU?

What causes the Scala compiler to say things like:

```
Expression of type Failure[Node] doesn't conform to expected type AbstractTypeU.
```

Update:
Not that it answers the question, but the fix turned out to be using flatMap, instead of map.

```
xmlElem flatMap (xmlObj =>
    try {
      Success((xmlObj \\ "SOMEELEMENT").head)
    }
    catch { case e: Exception => Failure(e) }
  )
```

When calling 'map', the error appeared for both the Success and Failure statements.

Comment: can you show some code where this exception occurs?

Comment: Isn't it easier to use option: `xmlElem flatMap (obj => (obj \\ "elem").headOption))`? Success & Failure shouldn't be used in your way

Comment: @AlexIv Yes, good point - that is how it started. But the call chain requires Try[Elem]. And there was a case where a caller was passing XML without the required element, causing an exception. The try/catch block puts the response back into a form that the callers can handle. (They do not expect exceptions, as all results are chained, and try/catch breaks functional composition.) `Either` was being used previously, but is not chainable like `Try[T]` so much more messy to deal with than Try. What would you suggest in this case?

Comment: @AlexIv What about `xmlElem flatMap (obj => Try((obj \\ "elem").head))`?

Comment: If your program requeres Try, then stick to it, it's not a bad design, but i would try to avoid it, btw you can transform Try to Option, by calling toOption, and continue with Option. If you still want to stick to Success/Failure style, then check out Scalaz Validation/NEL, it will give you good monadic chains. [Lil Tut](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Validation.html)

Comment: As for AbstactTypeU, as i understand Scala compiler uses such things for type checking during typer phase, but i'm not sure